# UITableView initial row selection

Tags: uitableview, row, selection

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I'm have a hard time programmatically setting the row selection in a tableView. The goal is to simply have a tableView open with a row already selected. The problem appears to be that I have to wait until the tableView is fully loaded before I can modify the selection.

I've read various strategies such as calling reloadData for the tableView in the viewController's viewWillAppear method, then immediately calling selectRowAtIndexPath for the target row. But when I do that, I get a range exception because the tableView has zero rows at that point. The UITableViewDelegate methods (numberOfRowsInSection, etc.) don't appear to be called immediately in response to reloadData (which makes sense if the table rows are drawn "lazily").

The only way I've been able to get this to work is to call selectRowAtIndexPath after a short delay, but then you can *see* the tableView scroll the selected row into view.

Surely, there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use another strategy. You can create a hidden table view, configure how you want and than show to user. Use the `tableview.hidden = YES`.

Comment: I considered that (hiding the tableView until it's fully configured), but then you have to figure out WHEN the tableView is finished loading (ie. when to unhide it). It seems like there should be an easier way. To see an example of what I'm trying to achieve, take a look at the Mail app on the iPad. When you click the folder button in portrait orientation, a popover window appears with the selected message row highlighted in the tableView.

Comment: As a follow-up to the "hide then show" strategy: it *sort* of works, but you see a "flash" of background before the table view suddenly appears -- not ideal.